# How to store dynamic input in maps

Tags: go

In Go, how should I put dynamic/user input in maps

```golang
func main() {
    mapp := make(map[int]string)
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        fmt.Scanf("%d %s", &mapp[i], &mapp[i])
    }
    fmt.Print(mapp)
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty new to go, but I found on other questions that you can define an empty interface like `hm := []interface{}{}` and `append` to it in your loop like `hm = append(hm, input...)` (you may have to make the inputs into an interface as well)

Comment: Map elements are not addressable. Get user input to variables first, then add those to the map: fmt.Scanf("%d %s",&num,&str) mapp[num]=str`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create a key-value pair on a map like that.

What you can do, is store the input in variables, and then create a map key-value pair with the input. Like this:

```
for i := 0 ; i < 5 ; i++ {
    var num int
    var text string
    fmt.Scanf("%d %s",&num,&text)
    mapp[num] = text
}
```